# How to count values that match a certain condition?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have file with number of columns  for example

**input file**

```
12  15  27  
5   6  48  
19  16  25  
17  23  37
```

etc

I want to count all the numbers (`X`) in column 2 for example that fulfill  the following condition `6 <= X < 20`

so the result would be `3` corresponding to the numbers **15**,**6** and **16**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is easy enough in a tool like `awk`

```
awk '$2>=6 && $2<20 { tot++ } END { print +tot}'
```

If you want to *sum* them then

```
awk '$2>=6 && $2<20 { tot += $2 } END { print +tot}'
```

Comment: Count them, not sum them.

Comment: Thanks; answer modified for both variants, just for completeness :-)

Comment: `print +tot` instead of `print tot` to report `0` when no record qualifies

Comment: Merged in `+tot` and removed unneeded version (we have to learn to through away code. I know it is hard, so I did it for you).

Comment: Edit rolled back; I have no attachment to code that took zero effort to write.  I left both versions there _deliberately_ to show the similarities between the two versions, which can help people learning `awk` to recognise standard patterns and solutions.

Answer (score 4):

For noted conditions is easy to go through all numbers need

```
grep -Ec '^[0-9]+\s+([6-9]|1[0-9])\b'
```